# PHP move_uploaded_file function errors in Safari but works in Chrome

Tags: php, google-chrome, mysqli, browser, safari

The following code uploads an image successfully in a Chrome browser but fails in Safari. Safari is up-to-date and cookies are allowed. Where am I going wrong?

```
<form action="" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="upload-btn-wrapper">
                  <button class="btn-2"><i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true"></i>Select Image</button>
                  <input type="file" name="avatar"  id="avatarbtn"/>
                </div>

<button type="submit" name="usDet-1" class="btn-2" style="margin-top: 20px;">Save Details</button>
</form>

<?php
$Edavatar = $_FILES['avatar']['name'];
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["avatar"]["tmp_name"];
$fileType = $_FILES["avatar"]["type"];
$fileSize = $_FILES["avatar"]["size"];
$fileErrorMsg = $_FILES["avatar"]["error"];

$kaboom = explode(".", $Edavatar);
$fileExt = end($kaboom);

$newfilename = rand(10,999999999999).".".$fileExt;

$folder ='doc/users/user-folder/profile/img';

$moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, "$folder/$newfilename");

if ($moveResult != true) 
{
    // Profile image upload failed, this occurs on Safari browser only.

}
else
{
    // Works fine on Chrome Browser     


}
?>
```

var_dump($_FILES)  result below

array(1) { ["avatar"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(15) "profile_img.jpg" ["type"]=> string(10) "image/jpeg" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/php9yHA7d" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(161313) } }

Comment: Your PHP code is executed on the server so it should make no difference what browser is being used. Can you perform a `var_dump($_FILES);` when used from Chrome and when used from Safari and add that data to your question.

Comment: Show us the html form and file input

Comment: Hi thanks for your speedy response.

Comment: The above code on testing other user accounts is fine. My bad!! Must be a permission issue on the user account in question.